# Customizing Bootstrap default button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Is it possible to style default Bootstrap button to look like this? Note that I would like to have an ASCII char in place of icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use pseudo-element selector :after or :before and add the letter to the pseuto-element via the property content